# Oracle function return table of record type that defined in package specification

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I have a function that gets a string and delimiter as an input parameters and return the the splitted strings as a table.
when I run this function:

```
create or replace PACKAGE split_pkg AS
TYPE triplex_record IS RECORD (
                id      NUMBER,
                data    VARCHAR2(4000),
                data1   VARCHAR2(4000),
                data2   VARCHAR2(4000)
                );
TYPE triplex_tab IS TABLE OF triplex_record;
FUNCTION triplex (p_txt IN VARCHAR2, p_delimiter IN VARCHAR2) RETURN triplex_tab ;
END split_pkg;
/
create or replace PACKAGE BODY split_pkg AS
FUNCTION triplex (p_txt IN VARCHAR2, p_delimiter IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN triplex_tab
AS
    triplex_tbl     triplex_tab := triplex_tab();
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..TRUNC((REGEXP_COUNT(p_txt , '[^' || p_delimiter || ']+'))/3)
    LOOP
        triplex_tbl.EXTEND;
        triplex_tbl(triplex_tbl.LAST).id := i;
        triplex_tbl(triplex_tbl.LAST).data := TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(p_txt, '[^' || p_delimiter || ']+' , 1, 3 * i - 2));
        triplex_tbl(triplex_tbl.LAST).data1 := TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(p_txt, '[^' || p_delimiter || ']+' , 1, 3 * i - 1));
        triplex_tbl(triplex_tbl.LAST).data2 := TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(p_txt, '[^' || p_delimiter || ']+' , 1, 3 * i));
        --PIPE ROW(triplex_tbl);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN triplex_tbl;
END triplex;
END split_pkg;
```

I get below error:

> ORA-00902: invalid datatype

I have no problem if create as a PIPELINED function and I only want to define my TYPEs in PACKAGE's header with RECORD TYPE not at schema level with CREATE TYPE. How can do that?

Comment: Where do you get the error?  When compiling the package body?  When calling the function?  How are you calling the function?

Comment: @Justin Cave , The package compiles without any errors, I got error when run 'SELECT * FROM TABLE(SPLIT_PKG.TRIPLEX('_sample text_' , ','));'

Comment: I suspect you can't get there from here.  This article http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2015/04/table-functions-introduction-and.html includes a pretty good rundown of your options.  Depending on exactly what you are trying to accomplish, there may be alternate ways to structure your code (including populating a local collection and passing that to the `table` function) but it's hard to guess whether those alternatives would work for you.  I'd strongly suggest that you just define the type in SQL.

Comment: @Justin Cave , if I define all of types that i need in my procedures and functions with "CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE..." , it will be confusing so i want to define each of them in their package's header.

Comment: Then the trade-off you can't use them in a pure SQL statement.   If your SQL statement is in a PL/SQL block, it may be acceptable for you to define a local variable of your collection type, call the function to populate that collection, and then later pass that collection to the `table` function (something that is new in 12.1).

Answer (score 2):

Not seeing an issue with the package:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  triplets SPLIT_PKG.triplex_tab;
BEGIN
  triplets := split_pkg.triplex( 'a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3,d1', ',' );
  FOR i IN 1 .. triplets.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( triplets(i).data );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( triplets(i).data1 );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( triplets(i).data2 );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '------' );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**Outputs**:

```
anonymous block completed
a1
a2
a3
------
b1
b2
b3
------
c1
c2
c3
------
```

However, if you want to use the results in SQL then you will need to define the types in SQL rather than in the package.

```
CREATE TYPE triplex_obj IS OBJECT (
  id      NUMBER,
  data    VARCHAR2(4000),
  data1   VARCHAR2(4000),
  data2   VARCHAR2(4000)
);

CREATE TYPE triplex_tab IS TABLE OF triplex_obj;

create or replace PACKAGE split_pkg AS
FUNCTION triplex (p_txt IN VARCHAR2, p_delimiter IN VARCHAR2) RETURN triplex_tab ;
END split_pkg;
/
SHOW ERRORS;

create or replace PACKAGE BODY split_pkg AS
FUNCTION triplex (p_txt IN VARCHAR2, p_delimiter IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN triplex_tab
AS
    triplex_tbl     triplex_tab := triplex_tab();
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..TRUNC((REGEXP_COUNT(p_txt , '[^' || p_delimiter || ']+'))/3)
    LOOP
        triplex_tbl.EXTEND;
        triplex_tbl(triplex_tbl.LAST) := triplex_obj(
          i,
          TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(p_txt, '[^' || p_delimiter || ']+' , 1, 3 * i - 2)),
          TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(p_txt, '[^' || p_delimiter || ']+' , 1, 3 * i - 1)),
          TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(p_txt, '[^' || p_delimiter || ']+' , 1, 3 * i - 0))
        );
    END LOOP;
    RETURN triplex_tbl;
END triplex;
END split_pkg;
/
SHOW ERRORS;
```

Then:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
  triplets triplex_tab;
BEGIN
  triplets := split_pkg.triplex( 'a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3,d1', ',' );
  FOR i IN 1 .. triplets.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( triplets(i).data );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( triplets(i).data1 );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( triplets(i).data2 );
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( '------' );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Gives the same output as above but you can also do:

```
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE( split_pkg.triplex( 'a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3,c1,c2,c3,d1', ',' ) );
```

which outputs:

```
id      Data    Data1   Data2
------- ------- ------- -------
1       a1      a2      a3
2       b1      b2      b3
3       c1      c2      c3
```

Comment: thank you alot , I know that if I define TYPEs in SQL level it will work, but I don't want to define them at SQL level, I only need to define them at package header and be able to query them like ...FROM TABLE(...)

Comment: You can't - you need to define the `TYPE`s at the SQL level if you want to use them in SQL - you can define them at either SQL or package (PL/SQL) level if you want to use them in PL/SQL.